# NullReferenceException on Timer.Change

Tags: c#, timer

In our production code we have a random exception '`System.NullReferenceException`' that comes every now and then. after some searching we see it coming from a '`DoWork`' function that is a callback of a '`System.Threading.Timer`'.

I have reduced the code to a minimum to reproduce the problem. It seems to happen when for '`dueTime`' a 0 is passed, and in the '`DoWork`' on the function '`_timer.Change`' the exception is thrown. below is sample code, if you press enter a couple of times, you should get the error (sometimes faster than other times). the locking around disposing is there for test, but it also happens without that.

Something that i noticed was that if the doWork does not contain a lot of work, so is almost instantly at the `_timer.Change`, it seems to happen more frequently

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace TimerFault
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TimerTest2> timers = new List<TimerTest2>();

        while (true)
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++)
            {
                timers.Add(new TimerTest2());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

            timers.ForEach(x => x.Dispose());

            timers.Clear();
        }
    }

    public class TimerTest2 : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly System.Threading.Timer _timer;
        public TimerTest2()
        {
            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(DoWork, null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        bool isDisposed = false;
        readonly object locker = new object();

        public void Dispose()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                isDisposed = true;
                _timer.Dispose();
            }
        }

        void DoWork(object state)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {

                if (!isDisposed)
                    _timer.Change(100, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The full exception details are folowing:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=TimerFault
  StackTrace:
   at TimerFault.Program.TimerTest2.DoWork(Object state) in D:\Visual 
Studio\Projects\TimerFault\TimerFault\Program.cs:line 52
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext 
executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean 
preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext 
executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean 
preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
```

Am i doing something wrong? i cant seem to get it.
Again: The code is reduced, this is not the actual production code.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code, mashed the enter key and there was no exception or anything obviously weird, what version of .Net are you running under?  Can you add a full stack trace?

Comment: @AlexK. I tested it on .Net 4.0 and encountered the described problem.

Comment: @Jeffrey Can you reproduce the problem if you define the `isDisposed` field as `volatile`?

Comment: @AlexK.I tried it with .net 2.0, 4.5 and 4.7.2. it happens on all those frameworks. Also i edited my question with the exception details.

Comment: @DudiKeleti Yes it also happens when i make the field volatile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe i have found the answer, it it quite logical if i think about it now, but it was 
counter intuitive for me.

If the `dueTime` of the timer is set to 0, it will fire the `doWork` function as soon as possible, even if the constructor of the timer is not yet completed, ad the _timer field is not yet set to the instance of the timer. So the `doWork` function gets called, and tries to call the Change function on the timer before the _timer field of the class was set, and therefore gets a null reference exception. when debugging the _timer was never null, but it was probably set right after the exception happend, and before the program was set to break state.

if i change the constructor to the folowing the exception does not get thrown anymore:

```
public TimerTest2()
{
    _timer = new Timer(DoWork);
    _timer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```